# Return "Functional Interface" in C#

Tags: c#

First I would like to say that I have some background in Java and I'm now learning C#.

I've the following interface:

```
interface IComparer<T> {
  bool Equals(T a, T b)
}
```

And I want to implement the following method:

```
static IComparer<T> Compare(...) { }
```

If this were Java, I would simply return a lambda expression implementing a custom method that receives two `T`, and return a `bool`, but this isn't valid in C#.

Is there a way to solve this problem without having to create a new class that implements `IComparer` ?

PS: I don't want to use anything from the C# library that implements the "Equals" method, I'm aware that it exists, I just want to understand how to return something like "functional interface" from Java in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: No, lambda expressions can't implement interfaces in C#. [It's been proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4801) (now [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11929))

Comment: And how would a delegate come to play in this example? @Jcl

Comment: instead of returning an interface, you'd return a direct delegate (in your example, a `Func<bool, T, T>`)... it's definitely not the same, as it'd apply to a single method (which is why you can't return interfaces from lambdas... what if there were several methods defined? and properties?)

Comment: Java 8 implemented the concept of "functional interfaces" (interfaces with just one method), which is why it works... there's no such thing in the C# spec (yet, at least)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jcl I will try what you suggested. I made the parallel with "functional interfaces" because it's the only thing I know that it's comparable to what I want. I'm aware that the CLR doesn't support this concept. Thank you very much!

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>.Create((x, y) => ...)`

Comment: @TheApprentice I made an example using `Func`, in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NEJPIZ) (btw, it's `Func<T, T, bool>`, the result type is the last one, I mistook above and can't edit now)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is an anti-pattern in C#. Because we have delegates, there is no reason to implement a single-method interface for passing a function as you would in Java.

Comment: @ChrisShain it's nice for "interconnecting" with a F#, but yeah, delegates should be the way to go for normal usage

Comment: @Chris Shain I understand that, but this was a question made by a professor of mine to try to make the class see a connection between C# and Java. Now I understand that Delegates are the way to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I think the "functional interface" concept in Java is parallel to a delegate type in C#:

```
public delegate bool IComparer<T>(T a, T b);

static IComparer<T> Compare<T>() {
    return (a,b) => a.Equals(b);
}
```

Note that `Compare<T>` doesn't take any parameters, it doesn't need any to return an `IComparer<T>`.

You can use it like:

```
var e = Compare<int>();
var ans = e(1,2); // ans is false
```

However, unlike the functional interface in Java which seems to describe an object of an anonymous class, a delegate describes a single method.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can find constructor of generic `IComparer` in `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>.Default` static property. No need to implement your own then.

Comment: I know that there are implementations already but since I want to learn, I need to create one myself. This was just a simple example. @Artyom

Comment: @TheApprentice well, you can [look at the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs.html#ed43f9f1cdba27ec) and see how they did it, it is not too complicated.